# disable ESC key at the main page of a menu

Tags: c++

I have to send in advance, I'm still very inexperienced in C++. But I still want to learn a little about it, and I want to get involved in an open source project (https://github.com/xcSoar/xcsoar). Here I am working on improving a new menu to control the device running XCSoar (https://github.com/XCSoar/XCSoar/blob/master/src/OV/OpenVarioMenu.cpp). The menu responds to ESC and jumps back to the submenu above it. However, even on the first page, the menu responds to ESC and then closes, only to be reloaded. I would like to suppress this.

How to suppress the ESC key only on the first menu page?

I tried that:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
        {
            std::cout << "DUDE! You've pressed the escape key";
            std::cin.ignore();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As the code is cross platform _",,,XCSoar is a tactical glide computer for Android, Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows.,,,"_ are you sure that adding WinAPI calls (`GetAsyncKeyState`) is the correct action to address this issue ?

Comment: It seems to be not the correct action

Answer (score 0):

I found something, that almost works:

```
  bool KeyPress(unsigned key_code) noexcept override {
    CancelTimer();
    
  /* ignore escape key at first menu page */
    switch (key_code) {
    case KEY_ESCAPE:
      StartXCSoar();
      break;

    default:
      return false;
    }
    return RowFormWidget::KeyPress(key_code);
  }
```

I used StartXCSoar(); for testing if it works in general. In that case XCSoar starts, but the escape key is not cancelled. After leaving XCSoar the escape command will be executed. I think I have to delete the escape command.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
  bool KeyPress(unsigned key_code) noexcept override {
    CancelTimer();

  /* ignore escape key at first menu page */
    if (key_code != KEY_ESCAPE) {
        return RowFormWidget::KeyPress(key_code);
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
  }
```